# Am I about to ask for recommendations?

Tags: discussion

So I had a play with the new Visual Studio vNext ASP.NET5 projects last night.

It seems that MS have thrown out almost all the proprietary build tools and replaced them with grunt based builds.

So now I want to duplicate old functionality using this new way of building.

So, when I ask "how do I replicate such and such functionality", effectively I'm looking for a package recommendation to run under grunt.

How do I couch this kind of question?

Comment: How do I accomplish X with Y tool that I could do with previous version/tool Z isn't a recommendation question in my book. It could certainly *lead* to a recommendation, but there is also "You can't" or "Use this special setting" or "Change your config file this way".

Comment: I agree with @BradleyDotNet - if expressed well, this does not have to be asking for a recommendation at all.

Comment: It struck me that in the grunt ecosystem, there seems to be several ways to skin every species of cat. My worry is that it would attract opinions and "religions".

Comment: It might, then again, so does "How do I add controls dynamically in WPF". The phrasing I used (which was my translation of your original statement) seems objective enough to me.

Comment: The care you are taking here to try to ask your question in the best way possible stands in such stark contrast to the disregard some others portray. I'm also very curious about the topic of your question, not having had time to do more than skim an occasional article about the new stuff there!

Answer (score 14):

I think with careful wording, you can easily ask an on-topic question.

You have some specific example of what you're looking for (for instance, some Visual Studio 2013 built-in functionality or build tool). You have a lack of that functionality in a new version (Visual Studio 2015). Your question should be:

> How can I replicate VS2013 (or whatever release) {functionality} in VS2015?

which, is not asking for a recommendation. Beware though, you might end up with an answer like:

> You can't.

Hopefully, the answerer will have insight as to why, but this is always a possibility with these kinds of questions.

---

Since I have some experience with ASP.NET 5 and VS2015 preview, I'd like to add a few tips:

- In [ASP.NET Community Standup - Oct 7th, 2014 - CTP4, Package Managers, and more](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgbA2BxNweE&list=PL0M0zPgJ3HSftTAAHttA3JQU4vOjXFquF#t=1380), they mention that they will also be adding support for gulp at some point so that could make your transition easier if you're familiar with gulp.
- There is still an empty web template (named *ASP.NET 5.0 Empty*) that will allow you to use the new package management in ASP.NET 5 without all the front-end fluff that the Starter Web template comes with.
- If you haven't already, check out this really great overview of what the Starter Web template is providing and how to get started: http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/grunt-and-bower-in-visual-studio-2015